# Why is my understanding of the logic of this programming problem wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried answering this codewars problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52503c77e5b972f21600000e

---

These are the contents of the said problem:

Summary: Write a function which takes an array data of numbers and returns the largest difference in indexes j - i such that data[i] <= data[j]

The largestDifference takes an array of numbers. That array is not sorted. Do not sort it or change the order of the elements in any way, or their values.

Consider all of the pairs of numbers in the array where the first one is less than or equal to the second one.

From these, find a pair where their positions in the array are farthest apart.

Return the difference between the indexes of the two array elements in this pair.

---

We have to write a largestDifference function that accepts an array named data and returns the difference between the indexes of two array elements.

The problem gave this test case as an example:
[ 1, 2, 3] returns 2 because here j = 2 and i = 0 and 2 - 0 = 2

I understood the problem as trying to find a pair of elements in the array (where one element is smaller than the other) that creates the largest difference between their indices. However, I could not pass many of the test cases given. An example is [9, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, -1, -2]. I was expecting the answer to be 7 since the pair that gives the largest index is 9 and -2 where -2 < 9 and the index of -2 minus the index of 9 is 7, however the website was expecting the answer to be 2. I do not know why.

Here is my code for reference (I used python):

```
def largest_difference(data: list[int]):
    differences_list: list[int] = []

    left_index: int = 0
    right_index: int = 0
    pointer_index: int = len(data) - 1

    def move_index_left(data: list[int], pointer_index: int, left_index: int, differences_list: list[int]):
        left_index = pointer_index - 1

        while(True):
            if left_index == -1:
                break

            if data[left_index] < data[pointer_index]:
                differences_list.append(abs(pointer_index - left_index))

            left_index -= 1

        return differences_list


    def move_index_right(data: list[int], pointer_index: int, right_index: int, differences_list: list[int]):
        right_index = pointer_index + 1

        while(True):
            if right_index == len(data):
                break

            if data[right_index] < data[pointer_index]:
                differences_list.append(abs(pointer_index - right_index))

            right_index += 1

        return differences_list
        
    while(True):
        if pointer_index == -1:
            break

        if pointer_index == len(data) - 1:
            differences_list = move_index_left(data, pointer_index, left_index, differences_list)
            pointer_index -= 1

        elif pointer_index == 0:
            differences_list = move_index_right(data, pointer_index, right_index, differences_list)
            pointer_index -= 1

        else:
            differences_list = move_index_left(data, pointer_index, left_index, differences_list)
            differences_list = move_index_right(data, pointer_index, right_index, differences_list)
            pointer_index -= 1


    return max(differences_list)
```

Comment: If the "difference in index" is literally `j - i,` , the index of 9 minus the index of -2 is in fact -7.

Answer (score 3):

> I understood the problem as trying to find a pair of elements in the array (where one element is smaller than the other) that creates the largest difference between their indices.

That is not exactly what is asked. It is not just *"where one element is smaller"*, but where the *leftmost* of the two is smaller, *or equal*. The *"largest difference between their indices"* is not the absolute difference, but the greater index minus the lesser. In other words, you would always do `j-i`, not `abs(j-i)`, and at the same time make sure that `j>i` and that `data[i] <= data[j]`.

Concerning this misunderstanding, you need to correct `move_index_left` to do:

```
        if data[left_index] <= data[pointer_index]:
            differences_list.append(pointer_index - left_index)
```

And you need to correct `move_index_right` to do:

```
        if data[right_index] >= data[pointer_index]:
            differences_list.append(right_index - pointer_index)
```

There are however several other issues in your code:

- In the main loop you ignore the results of a previous iteration by overwriting `differences_list`. So only the last iteration of the main loop determines what is in `differences_list`. A similar thing happens in the `else` part where you make two calls that define `differences_list`. The result of the first call is thus thrown away and replaced by the second. In your approach it would make more sense to always *extend* this list with the additional results you get from such calls. You could use the `+=` assignment operator for that purpose.
- It could be that at the end `differences_list` is empty, and then the call to `max()` will raise an error. In such case your code should return 0, so it would make sense that before the main loop starts you initialise `differences_list = [0]`.
- Not a real problem, but the parameters `left_index` and `right_index` serve no purpose. Your `move_index_left` and `move_index_right` functions ignore the values that are passed as argument, and just re-initialise these parameter variables. They should just be local variables and not parameters. Consequently, these variables don't need to be defined at the top.
- Even if you make all of the above fixes, this algorithm is too slow. It compares all possible pairs, which means it has a time complexity of O(²), and in practice some of the larger inputs will take too much time to process.

All in all you need to rethink this and come up with a more efficient approach. *That* is the real challenge in this exercise.

#### O(log) time complexity

I notice that simple O(²) algorithm implementations still pass all the tests on CodeWars, which is a pity. This can be solved with O(log) time complexity. One idea to achieve that is to create a strictly decreasing subsequence from the input, and then you can use binary search to find the first index which maximizes the distance with another selected index -- which could start at the other end of the input and move backwards. This decreasing subsequence can be trimmed at the right as soon as an entry can never lead to a larger distance.

Here is a spoiler implementation:

> `from bisect import bisect_left
>
>  def largest_difference(data: list[int]):
>      max_dist = 0
>      # Collect the backwards ascending subsequence
>      #   starting from the right side, going backwards
>      asc_vals = data[-1:]
>      asc_idx  = [len(data) - 1]
>      for j in range(len(data) - 1, 0, -1):
>          val = data[j]
>          if val > asc_vals[-1]:
>              asc_vals.append(val)
>              asc_idx.append(j)
>      # Now we have a second index go from left to right
>      for i, val in enumerate(data):
>          if asc_idx[-1] - i <= max_dist:
>              # This entry in the subsequence cannot lead
>              #   to an improvement: remove it
>              asc_vals.pop()
>              asc_idx.pop()
>              if not asc_idx:
>                  break  # All done
>          # Find the rightmost index (using binary search
>          #   in the subsequence) that can be matched
>          loc = bisect_left(asc_vals, val)
>          if loc < len(asc_idx):
>              max_dist = max(max_dist, asc_idx[loc] - i)
>      return max_dist`

Comment: An `O(n log n)` solution can be quite a bit simpler: sort the pairs (value, index), then iterate over it once, keeping track of the minimum index.

Answer (score 1):

You are not permitted to sort or otherwise modify the input list. The simplest (but not most efficient) strategy is a nested loop as follows:

```
def largest_difference(data):
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(data)):
            if data[i] <= data[j]:
                d = max(d, j-i)
    return d
```